# totp-generator TypeError: JsSHA is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Am trying to build a totp-generator(just like what google timed-base authencator those) using react framework
am using this [bellstrand](https://github.com/bellstrand/totp-generator) module totp-generator to calculate my token but cant seems to make it work when i import the totp
[my react code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFQde.png) [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AT95.png) [my react App dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jGcj.png) i have import booth using ESM & CJS but didnt work N.B the module works with node.js

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "cypress-otp" package to generate OTP for Google timed-based authenticator. It worked for me.

Kindly use this link for your reference - https://github.com/NoriSte/cypress-otp#readme

Answer (score 0):

NPM package
http://npmjs.com/package/otplip
For Both TOTP and HOTP token generation..
with security key and QR Code.
Support ESM
import support